# Is setting a timeout on ObjectInputStream.readObject() safe?

Tags: java, timeout

I have an `ObjectInputStream` connected to an `ObjectOutputStream` through a socket, and I've been using `Socket.setSoTimeout()` to make `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` only block for 100ms. Since I started doing this I've been getting alot of `StreamCorruptedError`'s while calling `readObject()`. Could the timeout be to blame?

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is a solution for it, but it isn't `Socket.setSoTimeout()`.

Comment: I have a thread constantly getting new data through this function but I want to be able to stop it by setting a boolean to false. The thread has to keep polling the boolean and can't if it's blocked by `readObject()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a thread constantly getting new data through this function but I want to be able to stop it by setting a boolean to false. The thread has to keep polling the boolean and can't if it's blocked by readObject()

You can use Thread.interrupt to let it throw an `InterruptedException`, or in this case an `InterruptedIOException`. Make sure you don't swallow exceptions!

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't know about `InterruptedIOException`'s. Works fine now!

Answer (score 3):

If you set the timeout shorter than the normal delays which might occur in reading a stream, you can expect the timeout to be in effect when the stream is still properly active.

100 ms seems like a long time, but not if there's disk or network traffic involved.  Try timing out on something ridiculous, like a second.