# Terminating a Runnable() object from main()

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, runnable

This is my Runnable object(which is inside another class) :

```
private class StopFileCopy implements Runnable
{
     ObjectInputStream st;

     public Runnable(ObjectInputStream st)
     {
         this.st = st;
     }

     public void run()
     {
         if(st.read())
            stopWritingToFile = true;  // stopWritingToFile is an instance variable of the
                                       // class that contains this StopFileCopy class
     }
}
```

Now the problem is that a integer may or may not be written to the stream 'st'. If not, then I need to stop this StopFileCopy object instantly from outside the class. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just stop Runnable itself?

Comment: @biovamp , st.read() method continues trying to read an integer from the stream 'st'. I haven't got any idea about how I can notify the StopFileCopy class that the run() method should stop trying to read from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then your problem is, that `st.read()` may block forever. What you can do is that you can interrupt the running thread by calling [Thread.interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) after some time elapsed. (Do this from your main thread, on your runnable thread.) An alternative to this is to use a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) whom you pass your runnable then call its `get()` with timeout.
Btw, this is a similar question: [Is setting a timeout on ObjectInputStream.readObject() safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974742/is-setting-a-timeout-on-objectinputstream-readobject-safe)

---

One more thing that is important with interrupting. It won't stop blocking implicitly, you have to subclass `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable` and override `interrupt` to close the stream (then call `super.interrupt`). An alternative is to close the stream from an other thread.

Comment: I don't have very good concept about multithreding. Can you tell me how to interrupt a thread? And if a thread is interrupted at some point, does `st.read()` method stop working as well?

Comment: @JisanMahmud: added some more detail.